# How to catch a specific exception message thrown by a SpringBootApplication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jpa, jdbc

I have a Spring Boot application that connects to a database. The main class is this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OurApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(OurApplication.class, args); // this is line 27
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Throwable t = e;
            while (t != null) {
                System.out.println("MESSAGE="+t.getMessage());
                t = t.getCause();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to catch any exception thrown, and if the error message is the following, then I will handle it a certain way:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'service-account'@'%' to database 'our_database'
```

The problem is that that specific exception is not being caught by the `catch (Exception e)` block in the above code. When I run the application, I see the following output (some stack traces have been trimmed):

```
2023-06-06 13:38:52.988 ERROR 3040 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'service-account'@'%' to database 'our_database'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824)
    [...]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.mycompany.mypackage.OurApplicationApplication.main(OurApplicationApplication.java:27)

2023-06-06 13:38:52.988  WARN 3040 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'service-account'@'%' to database 'our_database'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824)
    [...]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.mycompany.mypackage.OurApplicationApplication.main(OurApplicationApplication.java:27)

2023-06-06 13:38:52.988 ERROR 3040 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2023-06-06 13:38:52.997  WARN 3040 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2023-06-06 13:38:52.997  INFO 3040 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-06 13:38:53.037  INFO 3040 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-06 13:38:53.077 ERROR 3040 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.mycompany.mypackage.OurApplicationApplication.main(OurApplicationApplication.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 33 common frames omitted

MESSAGE=Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
MESSAGE=Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
MESSAGE=Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Process finished with exit code 0
```

First of all, stack traces are being printed out that originate from `OurApplicationApplication.main(OurApplicationApplication.java:27)`, even though there is a `try/catch (Exception e)` around line 27, and the `catch` block does not print out the entire stack trace. How is that possible?

Second of all, at the bottom of the output you can see the `MESSAGE=` messages that print out the message for each exception in the chain. Why is it not printing out the `Access denied for user 'service-account'@'%' to database 'our_database'` message that can be seen from the stack traces?

Comment: "How is that possible?" - stacktrace is printed before catch/"inside L27". "Why is it not printing(?)" - (probably) because it is not "cause" but "mapped/translated";)

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution :

Exception handlers in Spring Boot typically involve the use of the @ExceptionHandler annotation. By annotating a method with @ExceptionHandler, you can define how your application should handle specific exceptions.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotFoundException(NotFoundException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred");
    }
}
```

=> It's generally used for global exception handling into spring boot

Comment: So I edited my `OurApplication` class to remove the try/catch block, and I added a new method to the class with annotation `@ExceptionHandler(SQLSyntaxErrorException.class)` and that takes a single `SQLSyntaxErrorException` parameter. I also added a log message to the new method. When I run the application, I see the `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException` exception as before, however, I do not see the log message from the new method that I added, so it is not working.

Comment: AFAIK this only works when exceptions are thrown from controller methods. Not internal exceptions